# Can I use drag and drop class from jquery-ui in chrome extension popup?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, crossrider

I am developing in crossrider platform.
I have to say that the draggable and dropable functions works fine in firefox popup, but doesnt in chrome popup!.
There is any restriction which you might know that exist in chrome popup extension?

Comment: Whilst there are no known restrictions, it's possible that something in the jQuery-UI library is not compatible with the Chrome popup when running in the extension. I suggest debugging by adding well placed log messages to your code and [viewing them in the popup's console](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/howto_console_log-section-5). [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]